# Why not make everything private or public?

Tags: java, c#, object-oriented

In code there are private and public declarations. Why shouldn't I make everything private or make everything public?

Comment: For the same reasons those modifiers exist in the first place?...

Comment: Could you edit this and elaborate on why you think you *should* make everything public or private?  Right now, this question in its current form is likely to be closed as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: ... I mean ... are you trying to look at this as though it's some sort of thinly veiled socialism vs capitalism debate? That's the only way I can look at it that allows this question to make sense ... which is both astonishing and sad.

Comment: I guess you never wrote a program which contains more than one class, right?

Comment: This is a nonsense question that ignores `internal`.

Comment: I was thinking the very same. I want all my pojos to have public attributes. No more getter/setters. DRY ftw!

Comment: It's a good question for those designing the language, but we can't do anything about it other than create another wrapper language to fix it. The reality is that there is no reason that you shouldn't be able to give a hint to the compiler at the top of the file to treat everything as public/private/protected/package, this would avoid a lot of superfluous text from the source files where it makes sense to, effectively removing a lot of complaints about java having a lot of redundant statements that are obvious from the context and intent of them in the source file.

Answer (score 7):

## Why not making everything public?

Note that access modifiers exist in some languages, but not every language. Python, for instance, doesn't have access modifiers, but Python programmers still use a naming convention (names starting by an underscore) to mark some methods as unsuited to be called from other classes.

Classes communicate with others through *interfaces*. An interface is a contract through which a class tells to the world what other classes can do with it: what methods to call, with what parameters, etc.

If you have a very basic class, it's easy to cram everything in a few basic public methods. Over time, the class will grow. From this moment, you have a choice:

- Either to continue putting more and more code in a few methods you had originally,
- Or create additional methods.

In the first case, you're screwed: code maintenance will drop quickly, and over time you'll find yourself unable to change the code any further.

In the second case, your methods remain small enough to be maintainable, but there are more and more of them. Your interface with the world grows, which becomes very problematic: other developers who need to call your method will simply become lost in hundreds of methods they *can* call. Even worse, some methods may be risky to call, because they put your class in an inconsistent state: you know that you need, for instance, call another method before or after the problematic one, but the world doesn't know it.

In this case, you'll switch them to be private. A few methods which allow the world to interact with your class will remain public; the methods which don't help other classes will remain hidden.

### Example

Imagine a class `Lamp` which can be turned `on()` and `off()` through a smartphone. So far so good, both methods are public.

However, it's a smart lamp. If there is no bulb, the lamp should emit a sound and refuse to turn on (because this would be risky: what if a child unplugged the bulb and is right now playing with the contacts?)

You can extend `on()` by:

- Adding a check which determines that the bulb is there,
- Acting on a previous condition to either turn the bulb on,
- Or emitting the sound.

A few changes like that, and your `on()` will become impossible to maintain. So instead, you'll create additional methods:

- `detectBulb()` determines if the bulb is there,
- `beep()` makes a sound.

Now your class provides four methods. However, there are no reasons to make them available to others: why would any other class `beep()` your lamp or why would it care whether the bulb is there or not?

So you make them private.

## Why not making everything private?

As already explained by JacquesB and EJoshuaS, making everything private in a class doesn't make sense: you'll only be able to initialize a new instance of the class (unless you make its constructor private as well), and nothing more, which... won't help you too much at creating amazing applications.

While private methods could still be accessed through Reflection, I can't imagine any valid case where you would like to do that.

You can of course make a program which has only one class where everything (except the constructor) is private. Again, there are few valid cases where you'll want to do that in a real application.

## Anything else?

Note that there is much more than `public` and `private`. There are methods which can be called from children, but not from other classes: this is called `protected`.

If your programming language has namespaces (Java and C# do), there are chances that there is also a `internal` access modifier which acts as `private` but at a scope of a namespace. It will usually be combined with other access modifiers forming either `public internal` or `protected internal`.

Answer (score 1):

Try making everything private. You will quickly note nothing will work, since no class is able to access any other class.

Comment: Unless you use reflection...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you can't make everything private (unless you intend to try to perform all your method calls on the object through reflection, which would kind of kill the point) - that would mean that your class would expose no functionality to other classes at all, which would make it rather pointless.

You definitely don't want to make everything public since many of your methods/fields/properties aren't exposing public-facing functionality, they're just there to implement it.